# Instagram api probleme with access_token

Tags: node.js, api, instagram

I am creating an application for instagram, i am getting the aceess_token , but all api calls return 404 response.

I am using nodejs.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You must get an access token from instagram api http://instagram.pixelunion.net/. try to use this link for instructions.

Comment: How does the access token generated from Pixel Union differ from the one from using OP's client ID?